# Can I travel visa free to Schengen countries with a Romanian work visa?

Tags: schengen, romania, long-stay-visas, nepali-citizens

I am from Nepal. I have a Romanian work permit. Since Romania is not in Schengen, do I need to apply for a visa if I have to travel to any Schengen country?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you will need a visa to visit the Schengen countries, and an extra visa for any non-Schengen countries you wish to visit. If you plan to leave the Schengen countries and then come back into them (e.g. Romania -> Schengen -> UK -> Schengen -> Romania) then you will need a multiple-entry Schengen visa.

All the info for you is [here](https://eeas.europa.eu/delegations/nepal_en/1592/Travel%20to%20the%20EU%20from%20Nepal).